# Android Studio: All User controls are floating at top of screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Problem: When i start my app, all user controls (editText, textview) are somehow floating on top of the screen while the layout in Android Studio is perfect.

Some Screenshots:

**How it is while running:**
[image: How it is]

**How it shows in Android Studio:**
[image: How it should be]

Thank you.

Comment: What layout type are you using? `RelativeLayout` or any other one?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: can you post xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using constraintLayout but you didn't define any constraints for your views

> To define a view's position in ConstraintLayout, you must add at least
>   one horizontal and one vertical constraint for the view. Each
>   constraint represents a connection or alignment to another view, the
>   parent layout, or an invisible guideline. Each constraint defines the
>   view's position along either the vertical or horizontal axis; so each
>   view must have a minimum of one constraint for each axis, but often
>   more are necessary.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

[image]

you can click the "wand icon" to infer constrains automatically or if your layout is not complex you can use RelativeLayout instead

Comment: Ahh now i understand these arrow things :D Thank you! #Answer